# How to display all the videos along with photos from camera album in documents?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, alassetslibrary

I am a newbie in iOS developing. I am trying to fetch all the photos and videos from camera album in my application's documents directory and then trying to compress them.
I am able to fetch only photos but not the videos. Please tell me as how to fetch the videos as well.
This is how my code looks for fetching the photos. I tried using MediaPlayer and MobileCoreServices frameworks also. But it dint work. Please help me with a code which is appropriate to my present code.

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(RImagePickerController *)imagePickerController didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
NSArray *rootDocumentPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
rootDocumentsDirectory = [rootDocumentPath objectAtIndex:0];
selectedImagesPath = [rootDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/Selected Images"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager]createDirectoryAtPath:selectedImagesPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];

if (imagePickerController.allowsMultipleSelection)
{
    mediaInfoArray = (NSArray *)info;
    for (i =0; i<mediaInfoArray.count ; i++)
    {
       NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([[mediaInfoArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"], 1.0);
        NSString *fileNameCount = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Image%d.png",selectedImagesPath,i];
        [data writeToFile:fileNameCount atomically:YES];
    }
    NSLog(@"Selected %d photos", mediaInfoArray.count);

}
   NSDictionary *mediaInfo = (NSDictionary *)info;
   NSLog(@"Selected: %@", mediaInfo);


[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**  Follow the new Link.

You can fetch all the videos from the album using this sample code:[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html)

Then you will get array of videos.Just use them as per your need.

Comment: In your code you have hard coded the URL of video files. But i want to get the access of those videos which are taken from the phone's camera.

Comment: I have edited the link earlier.This code will fetch all the videoes which are available in your album.Then if you want to scan the specified video you need you have to edit the same code as per your need.